# vuetify v-date-picker not start by first day of month in persian locale

Tags: datepicker, locale, vuetify.js, persian-calendar

Consider the following code

```
  <v-date-picker
    v-model="picker"
    :first-day-of-week="6"
    locale="fa"
  ></v-date-picker>
  <v-date-picker
    v-model="picker"
  ></v-date-picker>
```

As you can see in the following picture, In Persian calendar month starts by 12th which is the first day of May

[Code Output, Left side is Persian calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX3Cc.jpg)

Comment: I have the same problem. have you solved this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have this problem, unfortunately it's an open bug in Vuetify:

[[Bug Report] Problem with vuetify Persian datepicker year selection #11578](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/11578)

Which is a duplicate of:
[[Bug] Date picker new month is started at the end of previous month in 'FA-local'.](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/1892)

Personally, I had to user [vue-persian-datetime-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-persian-datetime-picker). It's pretty good, a simple api and easily customizable. Still, I hope they fix the problem with v-date-picker